# Object to string conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with object to string conversion in JavaScript. All objects inherit two conversion functions - `toString()` and `valueOf()`. When JavaScript tries to convert object into string, it searches for the `toString()` implementation and then for `valueOf()` implementation. So I overrode the `toString()` and `valueOf()` in this way:

```
var obj = {
x: 10,
y: 20,   
toString: function() {
    return "x = " + this.x + ", y = " + this.y;
},
valueOf: function() {
    return this.x + ", " + this.y;
}};
```

Concatenating the object literal with a string:

```
console.log("hello " + obj);
```

**OUTPUT** : `hello 10, 20`

Shouldn't the output be : `hello x = 10, y = 20`?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can get this object, in json format

Comment: @Abhishek, what I am expecting is when I try to concatenate any string with obj, the toString() should be called instead of valueOf().

Comment: @am_, hmm, I see.. Here I am not explicitly calling the toString() method, I am letting the JavaScript interpret the right function to invoke depending upon the conversion scenario... :)

Comment: @dInGd0nG Thanks for the indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `console.log("hello " + obj);`, the operator that performs type conversion of `obj` is `+`, called the adition operator.

in the addition operator, instead of being cast to a string, each argument is cast to a primitive value without a type hint. When an object is cast to a primitive without a type hint, the method `valueOf` is used if available. Only if `valueOf` is not callable or returns a non-primitive value, `toString` is used. If both `valueOf` and `toString` return a non-primitive value, a `TypeError` is thrown.

---

Quoting the specification:

http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1

> #### 11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )
>
> 1) Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
>   2) Let lval be GetValue(lref).
>   3) Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
>   4) Let rval be GetValue(rref).
>   5) Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
>   6) Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
>   7) If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   ...
>
> **NOTE 1** No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5 and 6.

http://es5.github.com/#x9.1

> #### 9.1 ToPrimitive
>
> ...
>
> **Object** - Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.8

> #### 8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]] (hint)
>
> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, unless O is a Date object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String.
>
> ...
>
> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with hint Number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1) Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
>   2) If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
> - Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
> - If val is a primitive value, return val.
>     ...

Comment: Thanks Jan for pointing me to the specs....

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding String with object, It tries to convert in primitive value that's the reason valueOf is called rather than toString

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: Object to primitive conversion can be possibly divided into "Object to string" OR "Object to a number". What you suggest which conversion type JavaScript has opted for in this case? I think "Object to string" because I am writing "hello " + obj i.e string concatenation.

Comment: you can see the NOTE section provided in your link.